# Morphia Return List of objects containing Java HashMap as a property?

Tags: mongodb, hashmap, morphia

I am doing a Java project and I am using morphia to interact with mongodb. So I have a Entity class which looks like

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(value = "CostMatrix",noClassnameStored = false)
public class CostMatrix implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private String id;

    private HashMap<String,Double> distances;

    private HashMap<String,Double> durations;
    public CostMatrix(){}

    public CostMatrix(String id, HashMap<String,Double>distances, HashMap<String,Double>durations) {
        this.id = id;
        this.distances = distances;
        this.durations = durations;
    }
}
```

Now if I retrieve a single object of this class morphia easily does so but if I try to get all the objects as a list with query like this

```
datastore.find(CostMatrix.class).asList()
```

then I get NullPointerException which means morphia returns nothing. Any thoughts about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following query:

Query myQuery = datastore.createQuery(CostMatrix.class);
myQuery.asList();

That should create a query, that searches for all CostMatrix objects and return those in a list.

Comment: I have tried but still I get Null pointer exception though mongo shell is returning all data items.